# Solve for X in the matrix equation below

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve for $X$ in the matrix equation below

$$(B(X^{−1} − I)A)^T + B= A^T$$

where $A^T$ represents the transpose of a matrix

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the matrices $\mathrm{A}$, $
\mathrm{B}$ are invertible and $\mathrm{I}$ is the identity matrix with same order as $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm{B}$, we have,
$$\mathrm{B(X^{-1} - I)A^T+B=A^T}$$

As we assumed that $\mathrm{B}$ is invertible, multiplying with $\mathrm{B^{-1}}$ on both sides, we get,

$$\mathrm{(X^{-1}-I)A^T+I=B^{-1}A^T}$$

Now multiplying with $\mathrm{(A^T)^{-1}}$ on both sides, we get,
$$\mathrm{X^{-1}-I+(A^T)^{-1}=B^{-1}}$$
Or, $$\mathrm{X^{-1}=I+B^{-1}+(A^{-1})^T}$$

Or, $$\mathrm{X=(I+B^{-1}+(A^{-1})^{T})^{-1}}$$